# EKS Multiple Account Architecture

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks

I'm looking into best practices relating to distributed EKS clusters (for multiple environments) across AWS Accounts with a shared services account servicing the environments and just looking for a sanity check on my logic.. I'm unable to find an exact layout from AWS which matches my design idea...

My thoughts are.. Account_1 would contain Route53, ACM, CloudFront, WAF and all other services which touch the underlying accounts. Account_2 for example would be staging, Account_3 would be production and so on. Accounts 2 & 3 can't see or speak to each other, but Account_1 can communicate to both of those and vice versa. Account_1 would contain the ELBs for ingress to the EKS clusters in both Account 2 & 3.

Does this make sense and does it seem sane?

Comment: There is good reason to have an infra/management account, but those services you have as an example will generally need to live in the same account as the cluster. Things like Cloudtrail logging, monitoring, etc can go in such an account: https://aws.amazon.com/organizations/getting-started/best-practices/

Comment: Ah yes you're right.. in that things like Route 53 will need to live in the environment accounts due to the subnets. I guess the theory behind my question was understanding the extent of peering VPCs from the services account below to the environment accounts.. of course.. presumably the load balancer can live in the services account if it's routing to an endpoint which is accessible via the VPC peering? But I'd be concerned about performance there maybe? My overall thought is to be able to have a single trafaek LB in the services account, which has an ingress and load balance between accounts

Comment: I would be more concerned about cross-az bandwidth charges, but I honestly don't know how that works. typically the NLB or ALB (ALB is required if you need WAF) is managed by the local cluster via aws-load-balancer controller. It handles security groups, creation of the load balancer, creation of targets, etc. I would recommend not mixing your prod and and non-prod traffic, you want to keep that isolated and many compliance requirements will compel you to do so.

Comment: Thanks for your note, they were good points. fwiw, I wasn't referring to mixing prod/staging traffic.. more having the ability to load balance between production clusters, and free up an entire cluster for things like maintenance, upgrades.. perhaps overkill but having the ability to do so would be cool. To do that I was more thinking that the ALBs would live in the cluster local accounts.. and the central prod LB in the services account would point to the ALB and so on. Perhaps it's just over complicated for the sake of it.. these are the things I'm trying to flesh out now and get some....

Comment: ...opinions on. I'm looking to build secure architecture, but also something which can by multi-nines uptime with the ability to be flexible and move traffic around. If we were to have multiple production clusters, we could intersync service meshes with Gloo and effectively move traffic from one cluster to another and enable use to have a get out of jail card should something go wrong.